# Android: Connecting to Tor SOCKS proxy at port 9150 throws a `SocketException`; only works if I install Tor Android app

Tags: android, kotlin, networking, proxy, tor

I'm creating an Android Jsoup web scraper app which connects to Tor via a SOCKS proxy at port 9150, (I want the requests to be completely anonymous):

```
    private const val TOR_PORT = 9040

    private fun establishJsoupConnection(url: String): Connection {
        return if (!useTor) {
            Jsoup.connect(url)
        } else {
            val socketAddress = InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", TOR_PORT)
            val proxy = Proxy(Proxy.Type.SOCKS, socketAddress)
            Jsoup.connect(url).proxy(proxy)
        }
    }
```

I am not using any special library to establish the connection, just the ones provided by the JDK. There are Tor libraries for Android out there, although I was told that they were not needed.

The issue is that whenever I run the code, I get the following exception:

```
java.net.SocketException: failed to connect to /127.0.0.1 (port 9150) from /127.0.0.1 (port 47806) after 30000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
```

The first thing I tried was to change the port number from 9040 to the many other Tor ports that you can connect to, this did not work. I had a similar issue in which changing the port did help, though in this case it didn't. Please note that the issue is only recreatable on Android, if I run the code on my desktop it works fine -- although I do have Tor installed on my desktop so it may also be why.

I tried other things as well, such as replacing `127.0.0.1` with `localhost` -- this did nothing to fix this. I have also tried looking online for other solutions as well but to no avail. I also tried to completely disable my firewall but that didn't fix things.

There was one thing that *did* 'temporarily' solve the issue, which was installing the Tor Android app from F-Droid.

**For some reason, the proxy only works if I install the Tor Android app** and then re-run the app, but if I uninstall the Tor Android app the exception comes back again.

What I'm guessing is that the Tor Android app is doing something in the background to allow a connection.

The Tor Android app (Tor) is complex, and I'll most likely never find out what it's 'doing' in the background to establish a connection, which is why I am asking for assistance.

I'm honestly surprised, I do not really have any idea in my head of what the app even could be doing to establish a connection. I thought that it could be something to do with firewall, although I've disabled firewall for my app and it's not doing a difference. It doesn't help as well that I'm new to networking in itself.

Comment: "For some reason, the proxy only works if I install the Tor Android app and then re-run the app". Yes, this is because the Tor app is responsible for connecting to and communicating with the Tor network. The app also is what runs the Tor SOCKS proxy on port 9150. Without running the Tor software, you cannot proxy over Tor. You will either need to run Orbot, or the Tor Browser app in order for your app to use that Tor proxy. Does that help and answer your question?

Comment: @drew010 Then how it works fine on my desktop computer? I even uninstalled Tor browser from my PC and it still works fine. Also, is there a way to connect to Tor without having to install the app? I know that there are some third party libraries you can use to establish a connection. Also a guy from the Tor forums said that the app should run fine and that I don't need any libraries to make a Tor connection.

Comment: Are you running Tor on your desktop? If not, I don't see how it could be working, or what would be listening on 9050/9150 as a SOCKS proxy, if not Tor. I am not aware of any 3rd party libraries that connect to Tor and offer the same SOCKS support that it does. Even if such a thing existed, it would need to be constantly updated to include new features/bugfixes/changes to the various Tor protocols and clients. You might be interested in Arti (https://gitlab.torproject.org/tpo/core/arti), a Tor client written in Rust, which will be more portable, but it is still being developed.

Comment: TLDR, if you want your app to connect to Tor using SOCKS, you'll need to run a Tor client on the local device or computer. On Android, this would be Tor Browser or Orbot, on Windows, the Tor expert bundle or browser.

Comment: @drew010 Thanks, what do you think of this library then: https://github.com/thaliproject/Tor_Onion_Proxy_Library -- is it also a scam? It claims: 'Provides a JAR and an AAR for embedding the Tor Onion Proxy into a Java or Android Program'

Comment: That project (Tor Onion Proxy Library) uses the core Tor binaries to connect to the network (see FAQ: Where did the binaries for the Tor OP come from?). Ultimately, it uses this project (https://github.com/guardianproject/tor-android) to build a Tor shared library for Android. If you use this, you will end up having to build new versions of your app when new Tor releases are available (otherwise you'll be running an older client).

Comment: @drew010 alright thanks mate, I guess I will mark this question as fixed. it's depressing for me, since I wanted to make anonymous jsoup requests, but it is what it is.

Comment: Good luck. Connecting to Tor, establishing circuits, and everything that makes it possible to anonymously relay requests over the network is no small feat. This is why the Tor software is required. I think your best (easiest?) bet here is to require that your Android users install and run Orbot (available in Play Store, F-Droid, direct APK download) before using your app. Then, your app can connect to the Tor SOCKS proxy that Orbot provides. Let Orbot handle the all Tor stuff. As Orbot updates come out, they can update that and you don't have to update your app/binaries at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to connect to Tor via a SOCKS proxy, your device must be connected to the Tor network and configured to open the SOCKS port for proxying over Tor.

The reason the proxy only works when you install and run the Tor Browser app is because that app connects to the Tor network and listens on port 9150 for SOCKS connections and sends them over Tor.

If you want your app to be able to make anonymous connections through Tor, then something on the device, or your app, needs to handle connecting to the network and relaying connections.

One simple way that you found is to run the Tor Browser app and configure your SOCKS client to use 127.0.0.1:9150. One advantage to this method is that Tor related updates are handled by the Tor Browser app. [Orbot](https://orbot.app/) is another app that could be used in the same way.

In the comments you pointed out a library that embeds a Tor executable used for connecting to Tor and facilitating connections. This is a good option if you don't want to depend on running another app to connect and run the Tor SOCKS proxy. The drawback is, you might need to update your app more frequently to include critical updates to the Tor binaries.

In summary, for the proxy to work, there has to be some software on the device that handles the Tor connection and provides the SOCKS port for you to use in your app.